# How to run a Windows bat file that will allow me to connect and disconnect specific displays?

Tags: display, batch-file, windows-11

[image: display setup]

I have three displays. Display 1 is a physical monitor connected via DP. Display 2 is a physical monitor connected via HDMI. Display 3 is a ***virtual*** monitor (using a dummy HDMI plug). I am using Windows 11 21H2.

I want to create two .bat scripts. The first bat script will enable ***only displays 1 and 2*** (display 3 will be disconnected). The second .bat script will enable ***only display 3*** (displays 1 and 2 will be disconnected).

How can I do this?

---

What I have tried so far:

I have been experimenting with `DisplaySwitch.exe`. The problem is that when I run `DisplaySwitch.exe /internal` the system uses only display 1 (displays 2 and 3 are disconnected).

I was hoping to find a simple command to do what I'm looking for, e.g., `DisplaySwitch.exe /1 /2` to use displays 1 and 2, and `DisplaySwitch.exe /3` to use display 3.

Comment: Windows does have a C# api that allows for this with `ChangeDisplaySettings()` like the answer here shows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462742/7411885, but might be more complicated than what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Try https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

Run it and read monitors id and serial number columns.
Then you may enable/disable monitors like

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable  monitor_identifier [monitor_identifier] 
MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable monitor_identifier [monitor_identifier]
```

As monitor identifier you can use

- Monitor ID, as it appears in the 'Monitor ID' column, for example: MONITOR\GSM59A4{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0008 -
- The serial number of the monitor, as it appears in the 'Monitor Serial Number' column.

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I'm looking for, the only issue is that, after some experimenting, it turns out that the names assigned (Display1, 2, 3) are not permanent. I.e., if I disable Display1, then Display2 becomes Display1. This means that my bat scripts won't work as intended. Is there a way to permanently name a Display to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you read 'Command-Line Options' on provided link? You can use: Monitor ID, as it appears in the 'Monitor ID' column, for example: MONITOR\GSM59A4\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0008
The serial number of the monitor, as it appears in the 'Monitor Serial Number' column.

Answer (score 0):

displayswitch has 4 parameters

- /internal
- /external
- /extend
- /clone

At a guess,

```
For 1 & 2 you want /extend
For 3 only, use /external (provided 2 is not connected)
```

I know /extend works but I don't have an HDMI connection to my ancient monitor so I can't test that one for you.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, what you are looking for is outside the scope of a batch script - unless it is simply used as a wrapper for another executable.

This functionality probably exists in PowerShell - check out the WMI classes - and certainly exists in .NET. If this is something that must be automated you should explore using one of those platforms to do it, or find a third party application that can handle this.

It's worth pointing out - though I am NOT suggesting you switch operating systems as a solution - that this could be easily accomplished in a bash script on a Linux system using common packages like xrandr.